# Find the general solution of second-order differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} - 14 \frac{dy}{dx} + 65y = 13 $$

For second order,

Let $$y = e^{mx} \\
y' = me^{mx} \\
y'' =m^2e^{mx}$$

So,

$$m^2e^{mx} - 14 me^{mx} + 65 e^{mx} = 13\\[6pt]
e^{mx}(m^2-14m+65) = 13$$

But I can not solve to get m (stuck here)

Please help

Comment: You need to solve the homogeneous part first (take the right-hand side of the equation to be equal to zero)

Then it's a simple matter of finding the non-homogeneous part of the solution, which in this case is very simple.

Comment: what shall i do after?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the homogeneous, we have:

$$m^2-14 m+65 = 0 \implies m_{1,2} = 7~ \pm~ 4i$$

This gives:

$$y_h(x) = e^{7 x} ( c_1 \sin 4 x+c_2  \cos 4 x)$$

For the particular, choose:

$$y_p(x) = a$$

Subbing back into ODE, we find $65 a = 13 \implies a = \dfrac{1}{5}$.

Thus, we have:

$$y(x) = y_h(x) + y_p(x) = e^{7 x} ( c_1 \sin 4 x+c_2  \cos 4 x) + \dfrac{1}{5}$$

Comment: Wow! You were/are on a roll!